# Is there a better way to catch only specific cause(s) of an exception?

Tags: java, exception

Given this stacktrace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException:
...
Caused by: com.mypackage.SpecificException
```

And this try-catch:

```
try {
    ts.init();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof SpecificException) {
        //do something
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I cannot modify the code for `SpecificException` nor the method that wraps this exception into a `RuntimeException`.

Is there a better way to catch only `SpecificException`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: catching specific Exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566450/java-catching-specific-exceptions)

Comment: @Sim it's not a duplicate because OP wants/needs to handle the cause of the `RuntimeException`, if any.

Comment: What is wrong with the solution you suggest?

Comment: @assylias I don't know for sure that anything is. I guess that part of my question is whether or not this is an acceptable practice.

Comment: It is acceptable in the "sometimes we have only bad alternatives" sense.  Whatever method wraps the `cause` in a `RuntimeException` thereby assumes that no method below it in the call stack can or will handle it other than generically, and that assumption is apparently incorrect.  It would be better if you didn't have to live with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only mechanism Java provides for selecting which exceptions to catch is the specific exceptions' classes.  If you want to discriminate between exceptions of the same class based on their causes, then you need to catch all exceptions of that class, as you demonstrate.

Note, however, that it is problematic to re-throw an exception once you've caught it, because that replaces the original stack trace with a new one specific to the context of the new `throw`.  That can make debugging a lot more difficult.  To avoid that, you would need to wrap the caught exception as the cause of a separate, new exception, and throw that.

Comment: Note, by the way, that if there is any chance that you would have multiple layers of (catch, wrap, throw) then you might need to check more than the cause of the exception you've caught: you might need also to check the cause's cause, and *that* exception's cause, etc..

Comment: +1. On the other hand, OP, you're encountering this because *a library you don't control is throwing exceptions that leak to your component's callers*. Wrapping your library's exceptions isn't always necessary or useful, but can provide you with more control and documentation over the exceptions that come out if your code. (This is especially important in API design.)