# java: multiple exception throwing

Tags: java, exception

I read one piece of codes:

```
public void myfunc() throws MyException {
       try {
            // codes here
        } catch(AlreadyExistsException e) {
            throw new sub1MyException("yyy"); // first catch block
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new sub2MyException("xxx"); // second catch block
        }
}
```

`sub1MyException` and `sub2MyException` are both sub-classes of `MyException`. `AlreadyExistsException` is **NOT** sub-class of `MyException`.

I have some questons:

**1, will `throw new sub1MyException("yyy");` be caught by the second catch block?**

2, Any anti-patterns in the above codes. I did some search but did not find any similar patterns or examples. If any, please leave a comment.

3, I think, it is not necessary to use so many sub-classes because exception messages already in the `Exception`. Custom messages such as `yyy` and `xxx` not very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: 1. is easy to test / 2. I would say no / 3. it's better not to rely on messages. I mean `new SomeException("error 1")` and for something else `new SomeException("error 2")` is most of the time a bad idea

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566450/java-catching-specific-exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, you'd have to nest a `try-catch` block inside your `catch` for that to happen.
2. Catching `Exception` is an anti-pattern in itself, but it's so widely used that people don't really care anymore. You shouldn't really catch `Exception` because then you basically have no idea what you are expecting (and `try-catch` blocks are about predictability). The only place in which you should blanket-catch `Exception` is in a general error handler that handles the final error dispatch (showing a big ugly error message, logging errors etc.)
3. If the only thing in which your errors differ is in the error message, then no, there's no use in differentiating them. If there's a difference in how they propagate (for example, one is a recoverable error and the other is a runtime error), then you should differentiate. The rule of the thumb is that you should only have different `Exception` classes if they differ in their propagation strategy (i.e. in which `try-catch` blocks they are handled in further down the road).

Answer (score 0):

1) no it won't. it's not inside the try-catch.

2 & 3 - it depends what you need to do. if you need to handle the different exceptions in a different manner, then do so. Otherwise you can just catch Exception.